# Is there an easy way to add a custom class to all of the elements of the jQuery-ui Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Long story short, Is there a way to add a certain class to each element of the datepicker? (i'm talking all the spans, tds, everything). I want to add the class to prevent my context-menu from hiding when I use the datepicker. (the CM hides whenever I click an element that doesn't have a certain class)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div *').addClass('myclass');
```

Not very efficient though, I suggest you examine other routes to achieve the desired result.